# How can I add a <span> tag to specific words in a textbox using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an input text box.
User has entered a text "I have the following question in mind"

Can I conditionally add a  tag to highlight the occurrence of a particular word, say "question"?

Comment: When you say "an input text box", what sort of element do you mean exactly? (`<span>`s aren't valid inside standard input elements)

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

You can't put a `<span>` in an `<input />` but you can use [`contenteditable`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content) to make an HTML element kind of behave like an input.

It can get quite complex quite fast. Maybe there are some libraries that can help you.

Answer (score -1):

Sure, if you use **ReactJS** you can listen on field using useEffect(() => callback, [array deps]). Like this:

```js
//Substitute "text" with your input text var

useEffect(()=>{
  //Do here the tag manipulation
},[text])
```

In **HTML5**

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Modify the text in the input field, then click outside the field to fire the onchange event.</p>

Enter some text: <input type="text" name="txt" value="Hello" onchange="myFunction(this.value)">

<script>
function myFunction(val) {
  //Insert here the logic
  //Read val and take your decision for change DOM
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Basically your answer is: «If you are using React, use the `useEffect` hook and implement the logic you need; if you are using plain JavaScript, use a function and implement the logic you need»... so, you are not answering. Furthermore, even if the missing logic were not a problem, the suggestion would not work anyway for the reason explained by DBS and Halcyon.